# Including llvm, Value.h not found

Tags: macos, llvm

I'm trying to compile a program using llvm, following this tutorial, [writing a toy compiler](http://gnuu.org/2009/09/18/writing-your-own-toy-compiler/7/), but when I try to compile I keep getting a

```
'fatal error: 'llvm/Value.h' file not found'
```

I'm using llvm-config --cxxflags, and it's providing the compiler with the directory

```
-I/usr/local/Cellar/llvm/3.5.0/include
```

for the includes. Value.h appears to actualy be in the directory

```
/usr/local/Cellar/llvm/3.5.0/include/IR,
```

but if i add the IR in the include, then a missing header just pops up in a different file.

If it helps, the full llvm-config command i'm using is,

```
llvm-config --libs core jit native --cxxflags --ldflags
```

and it's output is,

```
-I/usr/local/Cellar/llvm/3.5.0/include  -D_DEBUG -D_GNU_SOURCE -D__STDC_CONSTANT_MACROS -D__STDC_FORMAT_MACROS -D__STDC_LIMIT_MACROS -O3  -std=c++11 -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -fno-exceptions -fno-rtti -fno-common -Woverloaded-virtual -Wcast-qual
-L/usr/local/Cellar/llvm/3.5.0/lib
-lLLVMX86Disassembler -lLLVMX86AsmParser -lLLVMX86CodeGen -lLLVMSelectionDAG -lLLVMAsmPrinter -lLLVMX86Desc -lLLVMObject -lLLVMMCParser -lLLVMBitReader -lLLVMX86Info -lLLVMX86AsmPrinter -lLLVMX86Utils -lLLVMJIT -lLLVMExecutionEngine -lLLVMCodeGen -lLLVMScalarOpts -lLLVMInstCombine -lLLVMTransformUtils -lLLVMipa -lLLVMAnalysis -lLLVMTarget -lLLVMMC -lLLVMCore -lLLVMSupport
```

I'm using osx 10.9.5 and llvm 3.5 installed with homebrew.

Any advice would be much appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 5):

I had this same issue going through the same tutorial. Here's how I fixed it on Ubuntu 14.04:

1. From the root directory I searched for the `Value.h` file.

   ```
   $ sudo find . -name Value.h
   ./usr/include/llvm-3.4/llvm/IR/Value.h
   ./usr/lib/llvm-3.4/include/lldb/Core/Value.h
   ```
2. I changed the include statement in the `node.h` file to

   ```
   #include <llvm/IR/Value.h>
   ```

Comment: Thanks, that fixed that error. Getting a bunch more now though. I starting to think that maybe my llvm version is different from the one in the tutorial.

Comment: I just happen to be going through the same tutorial when I stumbled across your question. I'm having quite a few issues with the tutorial being out-dated as well. If I work through all the issues, I'll provide a blog post and link it here.

Comment: I found it. The code has been updated and can be found at https://github.com/lsegal/my_toy_compiler.git. I did have to add the line `#include <llvm/IR/Constants.h>` to the `codegen.h` file, but other than that, the Makefile worked fine for me.

Comment: Thanks, that got rid of my include errors. Still can't get it to work though. What version of llvm are you using?

Comment: I am using version 3.4 for both clang and llvm. That's the latest stable version. This is just a recommendation, but I am doing all my developing inside a Vagrant instance. I just created a clean Ubuntu VM and `apt-get installed` everything on the Install (stable branch) on http://llvm.org/apt/. I did this to eliminate all the cross-compiler conflicts that kept coming up in Mac OS X.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include "values.h"
/* instead of */
#include <values.h>
```

or you don't have a values.h and you instead need:

```
#include <limits.h>
#include <float.h>
```

http://www.compbio.dundee.ac.uk/pipermail/discuss/2006-January/000025.html