# Troubleshooting: Missing Value.h File in LLVM Installation

Tags: compiler-construction, llvm

I attempted to create a toy compiler following the steps outlined in the article [Writing Your Own Toy Compiler](https://gnuu.org/2009/09/18/writing-your-own-toy-compiler/). Initially, I tried building it on Windows, where I installed Flex, Bison, and LLVM as instructed in the article. However, when I attempted to compile using the command:

```
g++ -o parser parser.cpp tokens.cpp main.cpp
```

I encountered an error stating that the `value.h` file was not found in LLVM. Upon inspecting my file explorer within the LLVM folder in Program Files, I confirmed that there was no file named `Value.h`. I even attempted to install version 3.5.0 of LLVM, but the file remained missing.

In my search for a solution, I stumbled upon this related answer on Stack Overflow: [Including LLVM Value.h not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26246769/including-llvm-value-h-not-found). However, even in that scenario, the IR folder mentioned in the answer was not present.

I am currently at an impasse due to this issue. Any assistance in resolving this would be greatly appreciated.

I'm looking for a response on Stack Overflow that breaks down the solution step by step and explains each step clearly.

Comment: Step 1. `git clone git@github.com:llvm/llvm-project.git`. Step 2. There is no step 2, actually. Step 1 left the file in llvm/include/llvm/IR. Note that the article is from 2009, so you may want a 15-year-old version of the file. An old git checkout will produce that, but do you really, really want to work code that old?